# Laravel testing remember me cookie

Tags: laravel

I am trying to test that the remember me cookie is being set.

Why am I not seeing any `remember_web_xxx` cookie in the response? The only cookie being set is `XSRF-TOKEN`.

```
/** @test */
public function bla()
{
    app('router')->get('/_tests/login', function () {
        auth()->loginUsingId(1, true);
    })->middleware('web');

    $response = $this->get('/_tests/login');
    dd($response->headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I am stupid. I forgot to create the user to login with. E.g.: `factory(User::class)->create();`